# Analyze query performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm in the progress of analyzing the query performance of my SQL Server 2019 SE, I expect to have the information of the query performance, like below:

Date_Time_Running, Func/Store_Proc, SQL_Command, Elapsed Time, Memory_Usage

Could anybody please help?

Thanks a lot in advance

Regards
Don

Answer (score 3):

You should start with some already available tools that are very useful for tracking query performance:

1. [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/) - This stored procedure (written by Adam Machanic) queries a few of the DMVs regarding active queries, and returns performance information such as how long they've been running for, the last wait type, the CPU time, if it's being blocked by another process, etc. The procedure is fairly lightweight, and I'd recommend setting up a job that logs the results to a table periodically. (Personally I'm logging it every 10 seconds on some of my servers, but that may be overkill for most.)
2. [The **Query Store**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) - This is an out-of-box feature in SQL Server 2019, and is very useful for automatically capturing information about your running queries, their performance, and potential issues with their query plans or during execution.
3. [The `sp_Blitz` suite](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) - This is a series of free procedures architected by multiple SQL Server experts, which have different performance monitoring purposes. Specifically for query performance analysis you can use `sp_BlitzCache` procedure, but all of them are helpful in relevant performance tuning ways as well. I'd also recommend logging the results of these procedures to a table periodically (at whatever rate is appropriate for your use case).

As briefly mentioned earlier, a lot of these procedures leverage some of the awesome [**DMVs (Dynamic Management Views)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-ver15) that Microsoft has released over the last few years. That's a good place to start if you're trying to architect your own performance monitoring queries out of curiosity. But the aforementioned resources are all very helpful for existing options, if you want something that already does the job.